# get the same order after applying group by on data frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pandas-groupby

I've a situation where before applying a group by on a data frame, the order was in ascending, however after applying the data frame order gets changed and its changing internally.

**here is the code sample:**
**DataFrame:** `

```
final_day_wise = daily_sales_data.loc [ : ,
                         ['Placement#',"Placement# Name" , "Date" , "Delivered Impressions" , "Clicks" , "CTR" , "Conversion" ,
                           "eCPA" , "Spend" ] ]`
```

The order of the values based on "placement#" column, which is in ascending order.

**Output:** so while applying group by it is actually changing the order in reverse or any other order.

```
startline = len ( placement_sales_data ) + len ( final_adsize ) + 18
        for placement , placement_df in final_day_wise.groupby ( 'Placement# Name' ):

            writing_daily_data = placement_df.to_excel ( self.config.writer , sheet_name = "Standard banner({})".format (
                self.config.IO_ID ) ,encoding = 'UTF-8' ,startcol = 1 ,
                                              startrow = startline , columns = ["Placement# Name"],index = False ,
                                              header = False , merge_cells = False)
            writing_daily_data_new = placement_df.to_excel ( self.config.writer , sheet_name = "Standard banner({})".format (
                self.config.IO_ID ) , startcol = 1 , startrow = startline+1 ,columns = ["Date","Delivered Impressions","Clicks","CTR",
                                                                                         "Conversion","eCPA","Spend"], index = False , header = True , merge_cells = False)

            startline += len(placement_df) + 5
```

so is there any function or anything that can keep the order same.

**Input. Daily Sales Data**[image]
**output:**[image: I want]

Comment: Could you post a few lines from `daily_sales_data`, as well as your current output, and your desired output?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler I've edited with images. please check

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
processed_df = df.groupby('col').agg(...).reset_index()

processed_df.sort_values(['col', 'Placement#'], ascending=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: So reset index is not working here. I'm not applying "agg" function. directly apply reset_index and its asking for use to "apply".

Comment: How would i get the values in same order